# What is the difference between USB port bind/unbind and autosuspend?

Tags: bash, usb

I have a small server, with Ubuntu OS, running 24/7, and with a script that is triggered only once a day to retrieve data from the net, and copy it to an external USB hard drive.
This data copy is managed through a bash script.
Roughly, the data copy starts at 00:00 and finishes at 5:00.

Because the external USB HDD is idle for a long period of time, I would like to start it only few minutes  before data copy, and switch it off few minutes after data copy, directly through my bash script.

I had a look, and mostly identified 2 solutions, which I am not able to differentiate.

#### 1. Using [`bind`/`unbind`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888752/ubuntu-doesnt-bind-usb-device-after-reboot).

```bsh
echo '1-2.2:1.0' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/r8712u/bind   # switch on
echo '1-2.2:1.0' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/r8712u/unbind # switch off
```

#### 2. Using `autosuspend`, from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux/12675749#12675749).

```bsh
echo "0" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/autosuspend_delay_ms"
echo "auto" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/control"
```

Please, what is the difference, and which one would be the most appropriate for my use case?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Have a good day, bests

Comment: I'm trying to power on/off usb drive using this command, what I can't figure out is how do you find out what's the bus-port number you put on the echo command.

Answer (score 3):

Your second option "autosuspend" let's the operating system's power management decide whether to drive down the device, with some rules about particular timeout or some automatism. It would still keep your disk available for other programs.

In your first option the "unbind" is similar to pulling the USB cable. This will bring up trouble if another script beside your's is using the disk. IMHO a "unbind/bind" combo would be more appropriate as a hard reset when some USB device does not react anymore for whatever resaon, e.g. because it shut off on its own decision.

So option 2 sounds more appropriate for your use-case.