# help using bind/unbind to power on/off USB drive

Tags: usb-drive, echo, bind, lsusb

I'm trying to power on/off an USB drive using bind/unbind command following [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622576/what-is-the-difference-between-usb-port-bind-unbind-and-autosuspend), can someone please point me to the right direction where to find tutorial/explanation on bind/unbind usb drive (found some posts but very old and commands are deprecated and I'm not that knowledgeable about linux to understand everything in man)? what I can't figure out is how to find the bus-port number in this sample echo command

```
echo '1-2.2:1.0' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/r8712u/bind   # switch on
```

in my case, I think I have to change the driver to usb-storage, so the command would be

```
echo '?-?.?:?.?' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/bind   # switch on
```

which command should I use to find the bus-port?

Answer (score 1):

After further search, found some tips in identifying usb device number [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994234/identify-disconnect-and-reconnect-usb-device-via-terminal), in my case, it was a Samsung USB drive, which is listed as device 2-2:1.0, so the command is

```
echo '2-2:1.0' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/unbind
echo '2-2:1.0' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/bind
```